# Getting the range of data from a list in Python

Tags: python, list, range, max, min

I have a set of data that is in a list. I am not sure how to make a function which can take the range of that data and return the min and max values in a tuple.

data:

```
[1,3,4,463,2,3,6,8,9,4,254,6,72]
```

my code at the moment:

```
def getrange(data):
    result=[]
    if i,c in data:
        range1 = min(data)
        range2 = max(data)
        result.append(range1, range2)
    return result
```

Comment: What is this line - `if i,c in data:` ? And is your question about just returning the max and min value of the data as a tuple?

Comment: It is not clear what you mean by "range of the data". Do you mean a range indicating a sub-list? Can you give examples showing input and desired output for the function you are trying to write?

Comment: don't you just want `min(data), max(data)`?

Comment: or `mins,maxs = sorted(lists)[0],sorted(lists)[-1]`

Answer (score 19, accepted):

This is a very straight forward question and you're very close. If what I have below isn't correct, then please edit your question to reflect what you would like.

Try this.

```
def minmax(val_list):
    min_val = min(val_list)
    max_val = max(val_list)

    return (min_val, max_val)
```

---

**Semantics**

> I have a set of data that is in a list.

Be careful here, you're using python terms in a contradictory manner. In python, there are both sets and lists. I could tell you meant list here but you could confuse people in the future. Remember, in python sets, tuples, and lists are all different from one another.

Here are the differences (taken from BlackJack's comment below)

```
Data Type | Immutable | Ordered | Unique Values
===============================================
  lists   |    no     |   yes   |      no
  tuples  |    yes    |   yes   |      no
   sets   |    no     |   no    |      yes
```

Immutable - the data type can't be changed after instantiation.

Ordered - the order of the elements within the data type are persistent.

Unique Values - the data type cannot have repeated values.

Comment: Thankyou that fixed my problem

Comment: Seems like its gonna be 2*O(n) (I know, I know, big-o discards constant) due to scanning iterable twice? (Unless you can know data is stored in sorted order). Not sure if there is a need to optimize and scan once, tracking min and max, OTOH perhaps min() and max() are executed at lower (more optimized levels)?

Comment: @DavidNeiss, you bring up a good point which is encapsulated in Renai's answer. While it's always good to look at the overall scalability of a solution, it seems as though ninja is just starting out and is still wrapping his head around the basics of python. My answer was to help him realize he didn't need the `result` list or the `if` statement.

Comment: @AustinA Renai's answer is still sorting the list twice. A simple optimized one-liner would be: `min, max = sorted(data)[::len(data)-1]`

Comment: Tuples and sets are not synonymous. Tuples are ordered, immutable, and can contain the same value multiple times.  Sets are unordered, mutable, and each value is unique.

Comment: Thanks for correcting me @BlackJack, I happen to never use tuples and when [I looked them up quickly](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/python_tuples.htm) I for some reason thought they were also sets. Silly error on my part. I've reflected this in my answer.

Comment: @JashandeepSohi, I have also never used [extended slices](https://docs.python.org/release/2.3.5/whatsnew/section-slices.html) before so thanks for bringing this up. I'm sure I've been introduced to them in the past but failed to ever use them. I think I ended up learning more with this question than Ninja.

Answer (score 3):

If You Are Looking To Get The Range Of The Numbers, You Can Use:

```
def getrange(numbers):
    return max(numbers) - min(numbers)
```

I've Also Constructed This Code That You Can Use In Finding Averages:

```
def average(numbers, type=None):
import statistics
try:
    statistics.mean(numbers)
except:
    raise RuntimeError('An Error Has Occured: List Not Specified (0018)')
if type == 'mean':
    return statistics.mean(numbers)
elif type == 'mode':
    return statistics.mode(numbers)
elif type == 'median':
    return statistics.median(numbers)
elif type == 'min':
    return min(numbers)
elif type == 'max':
    return max(numbers)
elif type == 'range':
    return max(numbers) - min(numbers)
elif type == None:
    return average(numbers, 'mean')
else:
    raise RuntimeError('An Error Has Occured: You Entered An Invalid Operation (0003)')
```

All You Need To Do Is Type `average([1, 2, 3])` To Get The Mean Average For 1, 2 And 3. For Other Commands, Do `average([1, 2, 3, 'median')` And This Will Give The Median Of The Numbers. You Can Change *median* to: **mean**, **mode**, **median**, **min**, **max** and **range**

Comment: People usually talk about the mean, when they say "average" and certainly never about the range, or min/max values. That being said, calculating averages has nothing to do with the original question.

Answer (score 1):

I like [NumPy's `percentile`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-dev/reference/generated/numpy.percentile.html) function for the ability to get multiple percentiles at once:

```
import numpy as np
print np.percentile([1,3,4,463,2,3,6,8,9,4,254,6,72], [0, 100])
```

Output:

```
[   1.  463.]
```

(The minimum is the 0 % percentile; and the maximum is the 100 % percentile.)

If you really need the result in a tuple, you can easily wrap it with `tuple(...)`.

Answer (score 0):

I just did this:

```
>>>data = [1,3,4,463,2,3,6,8,9,4,254,6,72]
>>>min_val = min(data)
>>>max_val = max (data)
>>>range_data = (min_val, max_val)
>>>print(range_data)
(1, 463)
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please [edit] your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply. [From Review](/review/late-answers/26237676)